# i cant use header nav in a folder or a seperate folder with index

Tags: php, html, file, path

sorry im a newbie i saw similar things but my question is slightly different, so my question is if my assets file includes header.php gallery.php and contact.php i cant use something like this to lead another link  :

```
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="assets/gallery .php">gallery </a></li>
```

or

```
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="../assets/gallery .php">gallery </a></li>
```

etc. because if im in gallery and clicking contact.php im having file path errors. you know it is becoming like assets/assets/contact.php what should the path be if header and other files are in a folder ?

also if my index.php is at root and if header is in assets then how should i include my index path in header nav link ?

Comment: I think you need to try with full path.

Comment: Okay, but why are you putting your _pages_ in different folders? You should put `gallery.php` and `contact.php` in the **root** folder also along with `index.php` and `header.php` in **assets**.

Comment: good question , because i just dont want it look messy, you know when we open root index and all other php files are randomly around

Answer (score 0):

while you're in the same folder `assets` you can just use the name of the php file to navigate like:

```
<li><a class="nav-link" href="gallery.php">gallery </a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">contact </a></li>
```

Comment: yes that works but that time since index will be at root index and gallery files or index and contact cant be opened repeatedly , it will say index link is problem

Comment: Since index is in the root navigating from assets folder to parent folder(root) use two dots like. ".. /index.php"

Comment: thank you , now the only thing is since i made the link ".. /index.php" and it is in header that means when im at index page if i click on "home" it will give another error because we are already at root page so when i click the link ".. /index.php" it will give error :/

Comment: Since you're not using OOP to handle your php (that would be better) you can create a config.php file in your root system, where you'll define the abs path of your like like: define('PATH', dirname(__FILE__)) ; then include that file on to of each file index, contact, gallery etc.. And your href link will be href="<?php  echo PATH.'galery';?>" etc..

Comment: Good luck hope to help you more

Comment: And use `dirname(__FILE__)  `instead of dirname(FILE)